# Closing Thumbnail goes to the All Pictures View

Tags: 2010, picture-library

I have added a picture library web part to a page.  When selecting the thumbnail (and viewing the picture properties), and then selecting close, I am taken back to the All Pictures View instead of back to the page.  If I select the Name and then close I am directed back to the page correctly.  SharePoint 2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this and found that the behaviour is the exact same in my 2010 environment.

Scenario 1 (clicking an image's thumbnail)

- Note that the picture property page (dispform.aspx) URL **does not**
  contain the query parameter "Source=" and as such, the user is not
  redirected back to the web part page when clicking "Close", as
  expected.

Scenario 2 (clicking an image's Name)

- The query parameter "Source=" **is present** and the redirection back to the web part page does occur when the user clicks "Close."

In order to change the behaviour in Scenario 1, consider modifying the function attached to the Close button on DispForm.aspx.

Comment: No problem, @carren - glad to help!